# Javascript why is it returns NaN?

Tags: javascript, string

My code is:

```
var inputtedCommand;
var input = document.getElementById("showInput");
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(e.which)
    console.log(e.key)

    var which = e.which
    var inputtedCommand = inputtedCommand + which;
    console.log(inputtedCommand)
    input.innerHTML = "- ", inputtedCommand;
});
```

And the `inputtedCommand` = NaN. How to make it to the pressed buttons?

Comment: `undefined + <any number>` will always return `NaN`

Comment: You're probably missing smth like `inputtedCommand = input.value` inside your event handler. Also the line where you assign `innerHTML` is invalid syntax.

Comment: i created a correct one here see this : https://jsfiddle.net/3ftw2qLc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you declare inputtedCommand as undefined:

```
var inputtedCommand;
```

then you try to add it to a number which will always return NaN

```
var inputtedCommand = inputtedCommand + which;
```

So change it to:

```
var inputtedCommand = 0;
var input = document.getElementById("showInput");
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    console.log(e.which)
    console.log(e.key)

    var which = e.which
    var inputtedCommand = inputtedCommand + which;
    console.log(inputtedCommand)
    input.innerHTML = "- ", inputtedCommand;
});
```

and it won't blow up.

Comment: It isn't working for me too....

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: I have the solution now!

Answer (score 0):

you must use ".value" property for access to input value

```
var input = document.getElementById("showInput").value;
```

Comment: `input` is only used for outputting the result, hence adding `.value` will break the script.

Comment: so initialize " inputtedCommand" with value . ( =0)